# Nested query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my query:

```
SELECT Real_acct.[ACCOUNT]
  ,[Mailto]
  ,[Site_addr_1]
  ,[Site_addr_2]
  ,[Site_addr_3]
  ,[State_Class]
  ,[Map_Facet]
  ,[Key_Map]
  ,[Neighborhood_Code]
  ,[Neighborhood_Group]
  ,[Econ_Area]
  ,[Yr_Impr]
  ,[Acreage]
  ,[Prior_Total_Market_Value]
  ,[Land_Value]
  ,[Improvement_Value]
  ,[Extra_features_Value]
  ,[Total_Appraised_Value]
  ,[Total_Building_Area]
  ,[Econ_Bld_Class]
  ,[LAND_USE_CODE]
  ,[PROPERTY_NAME]
  ,[Building_other].[UNITS]
  ,[NET_RENT_AREA]
  ,[Related_Account_Number]
  ,[Agent_ID]
  ,[Agent_Name]

FROM [Pdata].[dbo].[Real_acct] 
    LEFT JOIN [Pdata].[dbo].[Land] ON 
            (Real_acct.ACCOUNT = LAND.ACCOUNT)
    LEFT JOIN [Pdata].[dbo].[Building_other] ON 
            (Real_acct.ACCOUNT = Building_other.ACCOUNT)
    LEFT JOIN [Pdata].[dbo].[Parcel_tieback] ON 
            (Real_acct.ACCOUNT = Parcel_tieback.ACCOUNT)
    LEFT JOIN [Pdata].[dbo].[Real_acct_agents] ON 
            (Real_acct.ACCOUNT = Real_acct_agents.ACCOUNT)
```

I want to add this query as nested:

```
SELECT [ACCOUNT]
  ,[BUILDING_NUMBER]
  ,[FIXTURE_TYPE]
  ,[FIXTURE_DESCRIPTION]
  ,[UNITS]
FROM [Pdata].[dbo].[Fixtures]
WHERE FIXTURE_TYPE = 'OWR'
```

with Left join

How can I do this, please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I undrestand you well you need to add this do your query (aka DrivedTable) :

```
Left outer join(
SELECT [ACCOUNT]
  ,[BUILDING_NUMBER]
  ,[FIXTURE_TYPE]
  ,[FIXTURE_DESCRIPTION]
  ,[UNITS]
FROM [Pdata].[dbo].[Fixtures]
WHERE FIXTURE_TYPE = 'OWR') f on f.Account = Real_acct.ACCOUNT
```

### Based on comments

You can repeat this pattern as much as you want for example another one with 'WHT' in filters

```
Left outer join(
SELECT [ACCOUNT]
  ,[BUILDING_NUMBER]
  ,[FIXTURE_TYPE]
  ,[FIXTURE_DESCRIPTION]
  ,[UNITS]
FROM [Pdata].[dbo].[Fixtures]
WHERE FIXTURE_TYPE = 'WHT') f2 on f2.Account = Real_acct.ACCOUNT
```

Comment: could you please tell me where I place this query in the main query?

Comment: @user3574257 at the end

Comment: Great, it works. I have another question: I want to add another criteria with it WHERE FIXTURE_TYPE = 'WHT' and then first Units column would be "OWR UNITS" and Second Units column would be "WHT UNITS". How can I do this.

Comment: @AbzalAli I don't get it, can you add it under your question?

Comment: Actually here's I want two column in the main query, that comes from the nested query which one you wrote just before with "OWR" criteria as:Left outer join(
SELECT [ACCOUNT]
  ,[BUILDING_NUMBER]
  ,[FIXTURE_TYPE]
  ,[FIXTURE_DESCRIPTION]
  ,[UNITS]
FROM [Pdata].[dbo].[Fixtures]
WHERE FIXTURE_TYPE = 'OWR') f on f.Account = Real_acct.ACCOUNT

Comment: Actually here's I want two column in the main query, that will come from the nested query which one you wrote just before with "OWR" criteria as:Left outer join(
SELECT [ACCOUNT]
  ,[BUILDING_NUMBER]
  ,[FIXTURE_TYPE]
  ,[FIXTURE_DESCRIPTION]
  ,[UNITS]
FROM [Pdata].[dbo].[Fixtures]
WHERE FIXTURE_TYPE = 'OWR') f on f.Account = Real_acct.ACCOUNT                I want to use UNITS filed in Main query named OWR this is one and another column will be (WHERE FIXTURE_TYPE = 'WHT') will use in main query named WHT.

Comment: @AbzalAli If I understand you well, you need to add that columns in derived table select column and then they will be available in main query like f.[Fixture_Type] or any other columns. Also you can use this pattern twice, one for OWR and another for WHT. Seem my edited answer